# React - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: reactjs

Binding the firebase data to Dropdown with condition. 
getting the following error
'  Line 424:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
'

```
  <TextField
                        id="sp_Role"
                        select
                        label="Select Role"
                        fullWidth
                        required
                        className={classes.textField}
                        value={this.state.sp_Role}
                        helperText={this.state.sp_RoleError}
                        error={!!this.state.sp_RoleError}
                        onChange={this.handleChangedropdown('sp_Role')}
                        SelectProps={{
                          MenuProps: {
                            className: classes.menu,
                          },
                        }}
                        margin="normal"
                      >
                        {role && role.map(option =>
                         {option.role_ActiveFlag==="1" ?        ---424 line
                          (<MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.role_Name}>
                            {option.role_Name}
                          </MenuItem>)
                          :null
                        })}
                      </TextField>
```

Comment: Move first bracket `(` from line 425 to the end of line 424. And I think u should add `return` on the beginning of 424. (or change brackets to `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move first bracket `(` from line 425 to the end of line 424. And I think u should add return on the beginning of 424 or change brackets to ().